# Which is the best option for uniquely identifying a client state from Ajax to Servlet request?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm making an online multiplayer chess game using java servlet in the back-end. In
the front-end I'm using JavaScript, Ajax, Html. Client\Player request is sent through ajax request  to the servlet controller. Now, I want to know which is the best option for handling a client request\state. I don't want to use cookies. I know URL rewriting is an option for managing client session. Apart from these, what are the other efficient approach for managing client sessions? Is HttpSession Object is a good option for uniquely identifying client sessions?

Comment: Why not cookies?  Just curious what problem you're trying to solve that cookies don't work just fine for?

Comment: If the user doesn't allow cookies to store in the browser then cookies are not going to work. I just want to redirect a particular player move to another player. Assuming that, 100 players playing at the same time (each in a pair)

Comment: Good luck coding user state without cookies.  While it can be done, it's a lot more work keeping track of a given user when they navigate your site or login, leave and then come back.  If it's only for a single page with no page navigation, it is not as much work.  But, nearly all major web sites these days that support persistent user state just require cookies before they will operate correctly.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. `HttpSession` uses a cookie under the covers. Saying "I don't want to use cookies" also means "I don't want to use HTTP session".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpSession in turn uses cookie to identify session (JSESSIONID) , it will be automatically setup when session is created

If you really don't want to use cookies , then go for Token Based Authentication , there are lot of tutorials available online, but it need a little more work for token management. This is been used widely now

Update

quick search on token based authentication on google gives this,

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2014/11/header-based-stateless-token.html

http://www.javabydefault.com/2014/11/implementing-token-based-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks, do you have any link for token-based authentication tutorial in Servlet. In my chess agent, hundred player can play at a time each making a pair. My goal is to redirect one particular player request to another player(whom he is playing with).

Comment: token based authentication is used to identify the user, which in you case will be used an step1, step2 associate an unique id or session id representing both players info in server (may be in db), then when an move request comes figure out the other player info and then send it to that person using the uniqueId

Answer (score 0):

yes using sessionId will be good option for you you can get the seesionis by using the following code session.getId()

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about security, you need not worry about 'authentication' mechanisms.

For example, if you just want to differentiate between two clients, you can simply add an extra parameter like clientId in each of your requests.

It can work like this:

1. Create one global variable in javascript like `globalClientId =
   null;`
2. At the time of each request, send this as an extra parameter
3. If globalClientId is `null`, generate a 16-digit random number and
   store it (this will be done only on first time per page)

However, some disadvantages of this method compared to Cookies are:

1. It works only for one tab
2. It will be lost if that tab is closed